# Curious ouput of rails controller generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Cannot generate controller via (it doesn't appear in /app/controllers/) `rails generate controller StaticPages`
Output:

```
azureuser@host:~/railstutorial_apps/demo$ rails generate controller StaticPages --no-test-framework
/home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load': /home/azureuser/railstutorial_
/home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load': /home/azureuser/railst[0/1427]
apps/demo/config/initializers/session_store.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting end-of-input
ure to restart your server when you modify this file.
                               ^ (SyntaxError)
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/azureuser/railstutorial_apps/demo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_gemset/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/azureuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
azureuser@host:~/railstutorial_apps/demo$
```

Comment: You have a syntax error on `config/initializers/session_store.rb`. Please show us the content of this file

Comment: God, damn.
I had a real loss of my attention and even didn't try to read these lines D: 

Thank you.

P.S. the error was in missing comment sign '#'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, there is an error in the `config/initializers/session_store.rb`. After you fix this error you will be able to generate the controller.